# Generate year from %tc variable in Stata

Tags: date, stata

How can I generate a year from a Stata variable with this format `09sep1943 00:00:00` and it's stored as a `%tc` component?

Comment: Please post reproducible examples with an attempt at code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `%tc` is a display format which is nothing at all to do with storage type. See e.g. http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0067

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is amply documented. See `help datetime` and use `yofd(dofc())`.

```
. clear 

. set obs 1
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 1

. gen double datetime = clock("09sep1943 00:00:00", "DMY hms")

. format datetime %tc

. gen year = yofd(dofc(datetime))

. l

     +---------------------------+
     |           datetime   year |
     |---------------------------|
  1. | 09sep1943 00:00:00   1943 |
     +---------------------------+
```